# SSL Certificate Chain in a sacalable gear

Tags: openshift

I moved recently my app to a scalable gear, I was using a custom domain with a startcom certificate and it worked fine.

Now Android devices mark the certificate as invalid, I was googling and the problem occurs if you don't configure the ssl chain properly. I have configured it right but I did it one more time, however the problem remains.

According to this ssl checker https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/ the chain is not sended and Android continue showing https://refly.xyz as invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very possible that you have not combined your ssl certificate & chain certificate correctly.  You need to combine them into the same file (ssl certificate first i believe) and then upload that as your certificate, and your key file.  Don't upload anything into the chain form field.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. By the way I used openssl x509 -in mycert.crt -out mycert.pem -outform PEM to convert my crt certificate in a pem certificate and cat refly.pem chain.pem > full.pem to combine both of them.